# How can I remove fish scales?

Tags: fish

I bought two pieces of filets (900 grams each) of a large Asian carp.

To keep those in the fridge, I cut them into large pieces. However, I forgot that those filets still had scales on them.

Since the fish was large in size, the scales were moderately hard and were not easy to remove. Now when they were cut into pieces, it has become a daunting task.

Can anyone tell me how I can remove those fish scales without damaging the flesh or taste?

Answer (score 1):

If you're cooking them with the skin on, use a fish scaler, otherwise use a fillet or other thin-bladed knife to cut the skin off the filet.

Answer (score 0):

Getting enough of a grip to use a scaler is going to be a challenge, if you really want to keep the skin on then use a fork to hold it steady while you scale. If you have a large cutting board with a juice groove then push the tines of the fork through the fish into the groove, it will help keep it steady and give you purchase.

In practice this may still be very difficult, so it may be easier to cut the skin off. It's important to use the right technique for safety. A fillet knife is the best tool, you can also use a long, thin and sharp knife. Lay the fish on its side and push the knife upward through the fish, just under the skin, halfway down the side. Slowly cut away from you, angling the knife to stay just under the skin. Once you are done, spin it 180 degrees and cut from the middle to the outside again. Don't cut through the skin as it gives you something to hang on to. Once you have one side done flip it over and repeat the process.